# module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to use confluent_kafka:1.6.0 module in aws lambda function and in the **init** file in line 9 they have the following statement:
`os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)` which is used to import some dll file that the module need, but I keep getting an error that say: `"errorMessage": "module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'"`.
Facts:

1. os module does exist.
2. sys exist with version:3.8.8 `sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0)`
3. All my python libraries are in a separate layer from my lambda function
4. When I display function of os, add_dll_library doesn't come back as part of the list

Anyone got an idea of what why os does not have that method? and would I fix that in AWS lambda?

Comment: `add_dll_directory` is documented as only being available on Windows.  AWS runs Lambdas in a Linux environment.

Comment: i see, hmm how would you solve this problem then?

Comment: Open a bug with the module you're trying to use.  If they need to use this on Windows, then they need to make sure they're on windows before calling it.  Though, I'd make sure it's really confluent_kafka generating that error.  I see no evidence of them calling that function either now or in previous versions.

Comment: it's used in 1.6.0 and 1.6.1, here is a snippet of the code:
```if sys.version_info[:2] >= (3, 8):
        os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
    else:```

Comment: I don't see it in [their github](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/src/confluent_kafka/__init__.py).  At any rate, whoever's calling that on any platform needs to stop.

Comment: I see that now, it must be our company modified version in artifactory then. thank you

Comment: @AnonCoward I am under windows I got this message with Python 3.7 while I do not have it with Python 3.9.

Comment: @Olorin Ok?  Feel free to create a new SO question.  Unless you work at the same company as the poster here, it's unlikely to be the same cause.

Comment: @AnonCoward I was telling this for information, it does not cause a problem to me as I switched back to 3.9.x.

Comment: It gives the same error on Python9. Do you have any updates?

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty dumb reason that caused this AttributeError: after a long reference chain through initialization importing, the last package that actually triggered this error (for me) is numpy, which I copied and pasted directly into site-packages. The source that I copied from has a different python version. So maybe something was masked. I re-installed the numpy package through the correct version, and it works well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had encountered a problem and fortunately, I came across a helpful article that provided a solution:

Article Link: https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/issues/1462

The issue arose because I had initially downloaded the package from Windows. However, I then tried downloading the package from a Linux machine and installed it as a layer on AWS, which resolved the problem.

It is important to know the version of Python that you are using to download the installer package:

```
python --version
```

This version must match the one used in your Lambda function.