# "module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'" in aws lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, video-thumbnails

I'm facing an issue that `os` does not have an `add_dll_directory` attribute in the AWS lambda function on the trigger.

I have written code for creating a thumbnail of a video and I have tried it locally that's working fine but when I upload this function with the required libraries then I get this issue and still, I'm unable to resolve it. I did not get any help from the internet yet regarding this issue.

`that is an issue that I'm facing`

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1381, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1354, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 929, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 2, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/var/task/cv2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 112, in <module>
    _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2()
  File "/var/task/numpy/__init__.py", line 109, in _delvewheel_patch_1_5_2
    os.add_dll_directory(libs_dir)
```

`This is the code that I'm using for creating a thumbnail`

```
import json
import cv2
import tempfile
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def get_video_file(bucket, key):
    video_file = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)['Body'].read()
    return video_file


def upload_image_file(image_byte_data, bucket, key):
    s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key, Body=image_byte_data, ContentType="image/png")

def generate_thumbnail(video_byte_data):

    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".mp4", delete=False) as temp_file:
        temp_file_path = temp_file.name
        temp_file.write(video_byte_data)


    video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(temp_file_path, cv2.CAP_ANY)

    success, frame = video_capture.read()

    if success:
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

        thumbnail_image = Image.fromarray(frame_rgb)

        thumbnail_size = (320,320)
        thumbnail_image.resize(thumbnail_size)

        thumbnail_data = BytesIO()

        thumbnail_image.save(thumbnail_data, format='PNG')

        thumbnail_bytes = thumbnail_data.getvalue()

        return thumbnail_bytes
    else:
        raise ValueError('Unable to read video frame')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']


    video_file = get_video_file(bucket, key)
    image_output_file = generate_thumbnail(video_file)
    upload_image_file(image_output_file, "thumbnail876", key.split(".")[0]+".png")
    
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(
            {
                "message": "hello world",
            }
        ),
    }
```

Please can someone tell me why I'm facing this issue? and how can I resolve this? Thanks

Comment: It looks like you built this on a Windows device.  AWS Lambda runs in a Unix/Linux environment.  Can you rebuild for Linux?  See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66977579/module-os-has-no-attribute-add-dll-directory-python-3-8)

Comment: @stdunbar, Thanks for replying to me.
yes, I have built it on a Windows device. I have also created one more function on a Windows device and I uploaded it on lambda and that is working fine but getting this issue with another function that I have shown you above

Comment: Python uses so many native libraries that it's very possible that one library contains an O/S dependency when another may not.  If you're deploying to Lambda you need a Linux build.  I believe that WSL can do this though I haven't personally tried it.

Comment: os.add_dll_directory was added in python 3.8.  What version of Python are you using locally and in Lambda, and how did you package the numpy library for Lambda?

Comment: The fact that the name includes "DLL" suggests that it's only relevant to a Windows implementation of the `numpy` and `os` packages.

Comment: Correct.  My question still stands.  How is the package being created?

Comment: @stdunbar, now I have created a build through Linux and resolved that issue but now getting one more issue regarding ``numpy``  however I did not add that library 

``
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module lambda_function: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
Traceback (most recent call last):
``

Comment: @AnonCoward thanks for replying to me. I have created it in python3.10 and I have used the python3.12 version in lambda. but now I have created a build in the Linux machine the issue has been resolved but now getting another issue in lambda that ``Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there``

Comment: Thanks, @jarmod for replying to me. now I have created a packaged zip in Linux machine and uploaded it in lambda as a zip file now that issue is not coming but coming another issue is ``Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there``, can you please tell me about that.

Comment: Be aware that numpy is available as an AWS-managed Lambda Layer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75136603/how-to-import-numpy-using-layer-in-lambda-aws).

Comment: Okay @jarmod let me try it, however, I have installed these libraries ``pip install requests urllib3 numpy opencv-python-headless Pillow`` in the local directory in the Linux machine after that I created a zip of these packages and uploaded in lambda but when I trigger lambda then get this issue. ``Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda runtime doesn't provide Pillow or openCV, and you seem to have packaged Windows binary distributions of your dependencies with your Lambda code.

You need to package the distributions compatible with Amazon Linux and the architecture of your Lambda function (x86_64 or arm).

The easiest way to do this is create a layer.

1. Put the list of your dependencies (Pillow, opencv-python-headless, plus whatever else you need) into `requirements.txt`
2. Run these commands:

   ```
   pip install \
     --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 \
     --target=python \
     --implementation cp \
     --python-version 3.12 \
     --only-binary=:all: \
     --upgrade \
     -r requirements.txt
   zip -r imaging.zip python/
   ```

   If your Lambda is running on ARM, replace `manylinux2014_x86_64` with `manylinux2014_aarch64`
3. Create the layer from the resulting zip file and use it in your lambda.

Comment: Thanks, Quassnoi for replying to me. now ``module os has no attribute add_dll_directory`` has been resolved but getting one more issue that is ``Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch your python interpreter from there``

can you please tell me about that why I'm facing this issue? Thanks

Comment: @Spiral: did you follow instructions in this post?

Comment: Dear, I haven't tried it yet because first I tried with a Linux machine so the issue is solved but I have one more issue that I have shown you.

should I try this in the window and upload it into the lambda?

Comment: @Spiral: please don't call people you don't know "dear", it's rude and condescending, thank you. Your new question has nothing to do with the original. Please ask it as a separate question.

Comment: Okay sure, you are right. I'm just asking about your given material so that I can try in Windows.